# How to execute a4j:commandLink oncomplete only when validation has succeed?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, validation

I am using JSF2, Richfaces4 and Spring. I have a command link. On execute I save records and on complete I execute search to display records like following code.
Problem is that `fireSearch()` in oncomplete executes even if there is a validation error in form. I need to execute `fireSearch()` only when the record get saved successfully.

How can I the oncomplete only when validation has succeed?

```
<a4j:commandLink styleClass="button" action="#{myBean.save}" render="detail_form" execute="@form" oncomplete="fireSearch()">
<span> Save </span>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

RichFaces supports request based EL evaluation in `oncomplete` attribute. So you should be able to print [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) as if it's a JS condition.

For example,

```
oncomplete="if (#{!facesContext.validationFailed}) fireSearch()"
```

If validation has failed, this will ultimately result in

```
oncomplete="if (false) fireSearch()"
```

And thus the function won't be invoked.